How to group pinned software icons in the Windows 10 taskbar using native settings or FLOSS?
I'm looking for a way to organize the pinned icons in my Windows 10 taskbar into groups or folders. I prefer a solution using one of the following methods:

Windows 10 native settings or configurations
A cmd command or batch script
A PowerShell script
A Free/Libre and Open Source Software (FLOSS) solution

My goal is to better organize my frequently used applications in the taskbar, similar to how apps can be grouped in folders on a smartphone.
Has anyone successfully implemented such a grouping system? If so, could you please share your method or point me toward appropriate resources?
I'm open to creative solutions that don't involve proprietary software or significant modifications to the operating system.

There is a freeware utility called 7stacks that provides this feature
Unfortunately its latest version is 1.5 beta 2 from 2011, but
its installer is still available
on the author site http://alastria.com/  (by clicking the "7stacks final" link)
Despite being more than 10 years old, this tool seems to be still working fine in windows 11 (as shown in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8Q0DTI_lDQ )
